# Intermittement workItemIds error trying to navigate work items

Tags: tfs, tfs-2015, tfs-workitem

About 60% of the time that I am trying to navigate through or save work items I receive a popup like this: [image: popup]

Specifically, the error message `Value cannot be null. Parameter name: workItemIds` is always there, and using Fiddler the workItemIds post parameter (in fact all parameters) is missing when this error pops up.

Has anyone seen this? Is this a config thing I did?

The server version is 14.95.25229.0 (Tfs2015.Update2.1) and I'm using Win 10 Enterprise, Firefox primarily as a web client, and VS 2015 Pro update 3 to code in (though VS doesn't have/display the error).

Comment: What specific version are you running? I tried looking up the version string in https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/tfssetup/2013/11/21/what-version-of-team-foundation-server-do-i-have/ but it doesn't seem to align even to the RC releases

Comment: Sorry about that, I added them.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using **Team Field** in your team project, it seems this maybe the root cause.

You need to make sure that you make the team field which you use for it's a required field in the work item definition.

More detail info please take a look at this similar issue in *Martin's* Blog: [Issue [ TFS 2013 ] Value cannot be null. Parameter name: key](https://nkdagility.com/issue-tfs-2013-work-item-tracking-gives-you-value-cannot-be-null-parameter-name-key/)

Comment: I am not using Team Field but I have recently customized the template I am having a problem with. I spent the morning trying to compare my export with the default bug WITD but the XML formatting makes it difficult to compare. Any suggestions where else to check? E.g. How do I track down which field doesn't have the expected default (or how to relax the restriction)?

Comment: To try diffing the process template look at https://teamprojectmanager.codeplex.com/, but note that it does normalize some of the XML